# Trying to understand mongodb's findOne function's behaviour and why it's causing the following issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

What I am trying to do here is find a user by id and if the user is not found then I am adding it to the collection. However, if found, I simply want to push a new product into the existing user's document.

The issue here is the following if statement that is inside a for loop:

```
    for(var i=0; i < data.products.length; i++) {
        console.log("Product    
        found:"+!data.products[i].product.equals(req.body._id));
        //if the requested product is not found 
        if(!data.products[i].product.equals(req.body._id)){
            data.products.push({product: req.body._id, isAdded: true,
            quantity:1});         
        }
        console.log("Adding product.....");             
     }//for loop
```

It seems that the first iteration find the condition true even though I already have a product with the same id exists. It should be false as long as the id exists in my document. Would anyone be able to explain this behavior of Mongoose please?

The console.log inside the for loop is returning the following results:

```
    Product found:true
    Adding product.....
    Product found:false
    Adding product.....
    Product found:false
    Adding product.....
    Product found:false
    Adding product.....

    api.post('/me/cart', wagner.invoke(function(Cart) {
        return function(req, res, next) {
            console.log("new post request"+ req.headers['usr'] );

            Cart.findOne({userId: req.headers['usr']}, 
            function(err,data){
                if(err){
                    throw err;
                }
                console.log("found this..."+ (!data));
                //if No user is found add a new cart
                if(!data && data.length < 0){
                    var cart = new Cart();
                    cart.userId = req.headers['usr'];
                    cart.products.push({product: req.body._id,
                    quantity:1, isAdded:true});
                    cart.save(function(error, data) {
                        if (error){
                           return res.
                           status(status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).
                           json({ error: error.toString() });
                        };
                        return res.json({ product: data });
                    });
               }
               //if user is found updated found users cart
               else if (data){            
                   for(var i=0; i < data.products.length; i++){
                       //if the requested product is not found 
                       if(!data.products[i].product.equals(req.body._id)){
                           data.products.push({product: req.body._id,   
                           isAdded: true, quantity:1});         
                       }
                       console.log("Adding product.....");             
                   }//for loop             
                   data.save(function(err, updatedCart){
                       if(err)
                          throw err;
                       console.log(updatedCart);
                       return res.json(updatedCart);
                   });
               }//else if
            });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I was doing it wrong. Basic for loop fundamentals lol It is obvious that the condition would be true every time it does not find the product id and so will execute the push statement every time it does not find the id. Which will cause it to create duplicate data in the database. The **solution**  was to simply add boolean flag inside the if condition and turn it on if it does not find a value and then use that flag to save and push a new product.

P.s Was stuck with the missing semicolon type of issue for 3 days lol Only because i forgot about minor for loop fundamental. Anyways, mistakes are what teach us the best :D Enjoy.